# Enterprise CA/standalone CA

Tags: certificate-authority

As in standalone certificate authority we can take it offline after creating a subordinate CA, i want to know can we also create a subordinate CA in enterprise case and can take enterprise CA offline or not?

Comment: Why do you want to take Enterprise CA offline? It is supposed to be online.

Answer (score -1):

Any CA can be taken offline as long as it's not directly hosting its own CRL files (assuming you use CRLs) and you don't need to generate certs from it in the mean time. You just need to bring it back online often enough to keep the CRL files up to date based on whatever publishing interval you've set. You would also need to bring your offline root back online for the same reason. It's just usually a much longer interval.

Comment: is asubordinate CA possible in enterprise CA case?

Comment: Yes, a subordinate CA can be an enterprise CA. You can also have the reverse where the root CA is enterprise and the subordinate is standalone.